# Modelling the queues at a restaurant at a college

Tags: java, model, hashmap, queue, priority-queue

Here are the constraints:
The restaurant runs from 6am to 11:59 pm daily (hence opens at minute 360).

On average, a customer arrives at the restaurant every 5 minutes. (Hence 20% chance of a customer in one minute.)

The restaurant requires between 2 and 7 minutes to fill a customer order, and because there is only one person running the entire restaurant, the next customer in line will be served only after the food is served to the previous customer.

While the restaurant tries to serve everyone in the order they came in, some groups of people are given a priority. Seniors will be served before Juniors; juniors before sophomores; sophomores before freshmen.

So far, I have implemented the code below, using Java Priority Queues and Maps. I tried to identify each customer by the time they came in (ranging from 360 and onwards) and their grades. However, this is my first time using priority queues and maps, and I am not very sure if I'm doing things right—in fact, it returns this error below, which I'm not sure how to fix despite having consulted the APIs and some other java resources:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.base/java.util.AbstractMap$SimpleEntry cannot be cast to java.base/java.lang.Comparable

```js
import java.util.*;
import java.util.PriorityQueue;
import java.util.Comparator; 
import java.util.Map; 

class CustomerComparator implements Comparator<Customer>
{
   public int compare(Customer c1, Customer c2)
   {
      if(c1.grade < c2.grade)
         return 1; 
      else if(c1.grade > c2.grade)
         return -1;
      else
         return 0;  
   }
}

class Customer
{
   public int grade;
   public double waitingTime;
   
   public Customer(int grade, double waitingTime)
   {
      this.grade = grade;
      this.waitingTime = waitingTime;
   }
   
   public int getGrade()
   {
      return grade;
   }
   
   public double getWaitingTime()
   {
      return waitingTime; 
   }
}

public class RestaurantPriority
{
   public static Queue<Map.Entry<Integer, Integer>> Restaurant = new PriorityQueue<Map.Entry<Integer, Integer>>();
   public static int waitingTime = 2 + (int)(Math.random() * ((7 - 2) + 1));
   
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      RestaurantPriority(); 
   }
   
   public static void RestaurantPriority()
   {
      double rand = 0.0;
      boolean newCustomer = false;
      for(int i = 360; i<1440; i++)
      {
         if(Restaurant.isEmpty())
            waitingTime = 2 + (int)(Math.random() * ((7 - 2) + 1));
         if(i == 1439)
         {
            while(!Restaurant.isEmpty())
            {
               waitingTime--;
               if(waitingTime == 0)
               {
                  Restaurant.remove();
                  waitingTime = 2 + (int)(Math.random() * ((7 - 2) + 1));
               }
               System.out.println(i + ": " + Restaurant); 
               i++;
            }
         }
         rand = Math.random();
         if(rand >= 0.0 && rand < 0.2)
            newCustomer = true; 
         else
            newCustomer = false;
         if(newCustomer)
         {
            int grade = 0;
            double rand2 = Math.random();
            if(rand >= 0.0 && rand < 0.25)
               grade = 1;
            else if(rand >= 0.25 && rand < 0.5)
               grade = 2;
            else if(rand >= 0.5 && rand <0.75)
               grade = 3;
            else
               grade = 4; 
            Restaurant.add(new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry(grade,i)); 
         }
            
         if(!Restaurant.isEmpty())
         {
            waitingTime--;
            if(waitingTime == 0)
               Restaurant.poll(); 
         }
         if(!Restaurant.isEmpty() && waitingTime == 0)
         {
            waitingTime = 2 + (int)(Math.random() * ((7 - 2) + 1));
         }
         if (i<1439)
            System.out.println(i + ": " + Restaurant); 
      }
   }
}
```

(The entire code is all written in one file. I'm not sure if this is relevant information, but I thought it might help.)

I have been stuck at this for a few days now, and I'd really appreciate any help.

Comment: When you create PriorirtQueue, create with object that implements Comparable. Otherwise pass the comparator object in PriorityQueue constructor.   In your code, why do you have Customer class and CustomerComparator class? `Queue<Customer> Restaurant = new PriorityQueue<Customer>(new CustomerComparator());`

Comment: Take a look at PriorityQueue - https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/priority-queue-class-in-java-2/

Answer (score 0):

```
public class RestaurantPriority {

public static Queue<Customer> Restaurant = new PriorityQueue<Customer>(new CustomerComparator());
public static int waitingTime = 2 + (int) (Math.random() * ((7 - 2) + 1));

public static void main(String[] args) {
    RestaurantPriority();
}

public static void RestaurantPriority() {
    double rand = 0.0;
    boolean newCustomer = false;
    for (int i = 360; i < 1440; i++) {
        if (Restaurant.isEmpty()) {
            waitingTime = 2 + (int) (Math.random() * ((7 - 2) + 1));
        }
        if (i == 1439) {
            while (!Restaurant.isEmpty()) {
                waitingTime--;
                if (waitingTime == 0) {
                    Restaurant.remove();
                    waitingTime = 2 + (int) (Math.random() * ((7 - 2) + 1));
                }
                System.out.println(i + ": " + Restaurant);
                i++;
            }
        }
        rand = Math.random();
        if (rand >= 0.0 && rand < 0.2) {
            newCustomer = true;
        } else {
            newCustomer = false;
        }
        if (newCustomer) {
            int grade = 0;
            double rand2 = Math.random();
            if (rand >= 0.0 && rand < 0.25) {
                grade = 1;
            } else if (rand >= 0.25 && rand < 0.5) {
                grade = 2;
            } else if (rand >= 0.5 && rand < 0.75) {
                grade = 3;
            } else {
                grade = 4;
            }
            Restaurant.add(new Customer(grade, i));
        }

        if (!Restaurant.isEmpty()) {
            waitingTime--;
            if (waitingTime == 0) {
                Restaurant.poll();
            }
        }
        if (!Restaurant.isEmpty() && waitingTime == 0) {
            waitingTime = 2 + (int) (Math.random() * ((7 - 2) + 1));
        }
        if (i < 1439) {
            System.out.println(i + ": " + Restaurant);
        }
    }
}}
```

Comment: Oh, I didn't quite realise that—thank you! However, a problem I keep running to is, if there's someone already in line who's not a senior, and then a new senior customer pops up, the senior gets served first, even before the existing student's waiting time is not up. And then the existing student waits all over again. How can I prevent this—serve current student completely and then give priority to the senior?

Comment: I had thought checking if waitingTime == 0 would help (as in my codes), but that's apparently not the case

Answer (score 0):

You want to save Customers in the Queue not Maps. For the priority queue to know how to order them you need to give it a comparator.
One other more elegant solution might be to use the class Random instead of Math.random(). Random can give you integer with a defined upper bound. Further, you don't need a named comparator.

P.S. please try to use the java naming convention. https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html

```
    public static void RestaurantPriority() {
        Random random = new Random();
        Queue<Customer> customers = new PriorityQueue<>(Comparator.comparingInt(o -> o.grade));
        double servingTime = 0;
        for (int i = 360; i < 1440; i++) {
            if(servingTime <= 0 && !customers.isEmpty()){
                servingTime = customers.poll().waitingTime;
            }
            if (random.nextDouble()<0.20) {
                customers.add(new Customer(
                    random.nextInt(4),
                    random.nextInt(5)+2)
                );
            }
            servingTime--;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Oh, I didn't quite realise that—thank you! However, a problem I keep running to is, if there's someone already in line who's not a senior, and then a new senior customer pops up, the senior gets served first, even before the existing student's waiting time is not up. And then the existing student waits all over again. How can I prevent this—serve current student completely and then give priority to the senior?

Comment: I had thought checking if waitingTime == 0 would help (as in my codes), but that's apparently not the case

Comment: what exactly is waiting time in your case?. I used the waiting time of the customer as the time that the restaurant needs to fulfill his/her wish. This means if a junior customer is currently being served a senior can't interrupt. But if a junior comes second and then the rest of the day every 2 min comes a senior then the junior wont get his meal.